# 2D secure payment gateway list

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway

Can Any one provide only the **2D secure payment gateway (not paypal)** list which works well without any problem in **USA, UK Europe and UAE** countries only with minimal setup in **woo commerce platform**, 
Thanks for the comments in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with BlueSnap for a while, as a payment gateway. They have good coverage of Europe, US and I think also UAE – it's worth checking about that one specifically with them. I know they have a WooCommerce plugin (https://home.bluesnap.com/search/woocommerce/) that does 2D secure transactions, and it's very easy to setup. Hope it helps!